# About UcchistaGanapathi and why its regarded as highest Ganesha form

Tags: ganesha, tantra

I have heard about the UcchistaGanapathi mantras, and why this form of Lord Ganapathi is regarded as highest and more Tantric. However, am not sure whether its regarded  as highest! (saw in one article) even Saktimahaganapati is also can be regarded as most powerful or highest...

I heard about one mantra something having ending with `**likhe**`
whats its significance and dhyana etc
And I saw, considering this form of Ganesha in one article its being depicted as for achieving something not-so-good manner!.

Comment: Please read : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchchhishta_Ganapati

Comment: As per some sri vidya tradition its higher level

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is mentioned as the supreme form of Lord Ganesha but it's worship is different from the usual worship. Because it is done (as the word Ucchistha already indicates) in an impure state viz - after not being washed after eating.

This is mentioned as a secret Tantric method.

> sArabutamimam mantram na deyam yasya ksyachit |
>  Guhyam
> sarvAgameshva hitabudhyA prakAshitam ||
>  Na tithirna cha nakshtram
> nopavAso vidhiyate |
>  Yatheshtha chintayA mantrah
> sarva-kAmaphalapradah ||
>
> This essence-of-all mantra is kept secret in all the Tantras but revealed thinking
> about the world's benefit. In this mode of God's worship, there are no
> rules pertaining to Tithi-Nakshtra etc, neither fasting etc are
> required. Whichever desires the aspirant has while worshipping
> Ucchista-Ganapaty are all fulfilled.

The Rishi etc for the mantra you have mentioned is as follows:

> Shirasi sudhira rishayae namah mukhe nichrid gAyatri chandase namah
> hridi ucchishtaganapataye namah ||

Rishi-Sudhira; Chandah-Nichrid GAyatri; DevatA-Ucchishta Ganapaty.

DhyAnam for this form is as follows:

> Raktamurti ganeshancha sarva-Abharanbhushitam |
>  Raktavastram
> trinetrancha raktapadmAsane sthitam ||
>  Chaturbhujam mahAkAyam
> dvidantam sasmitAnanam |
>  Ishtancha dakshine haste dantancha
> tadadhahakare ||
>  PAshAnkushau cha hastAbyAm jatAmandalaveshtitam
> |
>  LalAtachandrarekhAdhyam sarva-alankArabhushitam ||
>
> The murti of the deity is of red-color; is decked with all kinds of
> ornaments; is wearing red-color garments. He has three eyes and is
> seated on a red lotus. The deity has four arms, his body is huge, has
> two tusks and the face is ever-similing. In the four hands, he is
> holding - vara-mudrA, a tusk, pAsha and an ankusha. The deity has jatA
> in his head and is having a crescent in the forehead as well.

After meditating upon the deity as having such a form, it is to be worshipped. 16,000 chants are required for Purascharana of the mantra.

The Sadhana is to be done spanned over Krishna Chaturthi to Shukla Chaturthi. And, as per some Tantras, a Shakti (a female co-sadhaka) is required in it.

And, the mantra Japa is always to be done while not being washed after eating.

> Bhuktocchistha japennityam ganeshoham

According to Garga Muni one should do the Japa in a secluded forest being smeared with red sandal paste and while chewing betel leaves.

> Anyamate sampujya modakam charvayan bhrigumate phalamashnan |
> Vibhishanamate mAmsanaivedyam datva tadeva khAdayan ||
>
> According to other Tantras, while chewing modakas, one should mentally
> chant the mantra; according to Bhrigu Muni while chewing fruits.
> According to Vibhishana, after offering naivedya meat to the deity,
> Japa to be done while eating that as Prasada.

Besides, there are many many other benefits of this Sadhana.

All the quotes are from [Brihat Tantra SAra's (2010) revised Edition](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm).

**EDIT:**

After seeing the following comment, I have gone through various Ganesha mantras found in TantrasArah (TS) and other books like Sarva Deva-Devi mantra kosha (SDDMK).

> sriman, i heard about another avastha(sankalpa) having Goddess
> sitting in Ganesha's lap...with Anar fruit in one of his hands! this
> prompted me, am curious :-) , to get more about this form!

The codes for Ucchista-Ganapaty mantra is given in both TS and SDDMK and is as follows:

> Om hasti-pishAchini khetadwayam |
>
> TantrAntare: Hastpadam samucchArya pishAchini padam tatah | DevarAjam
> sanetrancha kAntamishaswarAmbitam | Vahni-jAyAvadhirmantra-starAdyah
> sarvakAmadah | Pranava sthAne gamiti kechit | Hasti-pishAchini kheha
> agnivanitA gam tadAdita ..

The author recovers the codes that are he found in Tantras for the mantra.

Om hasti-pishAchini khe swAhA is the mantra but as per some Gam hasti-pishAchini khe swAhA is the mantra.

Lord Ganesha has many Mantras of which I have listed few below. I have checked the DhyAnams for all these forms.

**Mahagnesh mantra 1** - Om srim hrim klim glaum gam ganapataye ... vashamanaye swAhA ..

... Trinetram rasAdAshlishtam priyayA sapadmakarayA sAngasthayA santatam ...|

So, here Ganesha is being embraced by his consort, who is seated on his left. But this form is not Ucchista-Ganapaty.

**Mahaganesha 2** -

Hrim gam hrim mahAganapataye swAhA (12-letter)

In this form too on Lord Ganesha's lap his Shakti (consort) is seated, who is padma-kAntA vishishta (complexion is like that of lotus).

**MahAganapaty 3** -

Om hrim gam hrim vashamAnaya swAhA (11-letter)

Here too, Lord Ganesha is touching his consort's person with a lotus, and here the consort is dark-complexioned and she is holding a lotus.

**Heramba mantra** -

Here, Lord Ganesha is not accompanied with his Shakti.

**Haridra Ganesha mantra** -

Here too, Lord Ganesha is not accompanied with his Shakti.

In the Ucchista-Ganapaty form too, he is NOT accompanied by his Shakti as is shown in the DhyAnam.

Comment: I think it would be nichrid gayatri chhanda.please check

Comment: @Rickross , sriman, regarding explanation of below :  "... is decked with all kinds of ornaments; is wearing red-color garments. He has three eyes and is seated on a red lotus. .. " , am having a different opinion on this!

Comment: I hv given the Dhyana sloka for the following mantra "Om hasti-pishachini khe swaha" .. this is given as the Ucchishta Ganapaty mantra in Tantrasara .. you may be talking about some other Dhayna? @SaMolPP this is the mantra which was practiced by Kuvera too

Comment: sriman, i heard about another  avastha(sankalpa) having Goddess sitting in Ganesha's lap...with Anar fruit in one of his hands! this prompted me, am curious :-) , to get more about this form!

Comment: Ok I will chk for that Dhyan sloka and update tomorrow @SaMolPP but the one I gave is also for ucchistha ganapaty

Comment: Dhanyosmi, i  marked it as an answer!

Comment: @SaMolPP I hv updated the answer .. Ucchista-Ganapaty mantra is as given in my answer and not what some blog-spots mention.. at least Tantrasara gives different codes .. and the description of Ganesha is for that mantra

Comment: i am having a doubt on " Om hasti-pishAchini khe swAhA" --> , i think, its "....ili khe"  instead of  "..ini khe"... , am surprised how come, there is a name "pisachini"  occur in a Deva'as moolamantra!!! thats very strange thing!

Comment: The two books I consulted both give hasti-pisachini .. and Tantrasara is an authoritative book @SaMolPP

Comment: and Btw pisachi and pisachini both have similar meaning @SaMolPP

Comment: about that Heramba Ganapthi:- isnt it special? I never heard about Lord Ganapathi with 5 heads and sitting on Top of Lion!! :-) i will ask this as a separate thread.

Comment: Yes, Herambha is a special form of Ganapaty .. Ganesha actually has many forms .. and each has specific Dhyana slokas .. I hv given few of them in the answer @SaMolPP

Comment: Fantastic Answer Rickross Ji !!! Just curious about have you ever done Ucchistha Ganapati laghu/proper purushcharana ?

Comment: Thanks @Rāmachandra no, I have never done that.