# Confusion on Ucchista Ganesh appearance

Tags: ganesha

Many pics show Ucchista Ganesh with Devi and many in dancing form. What is the correct form of Ucchista Ganesh? What is the most basic mantra for chanting?

Comment: Appearance of a deity is based on the Dhyana Sloka. In the following answer I have given a Dhyana Sloka as well as a mantra for Ucchishta Ganapaty. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33763/4732

Comment: I want to know more about Uchishta Ganesha, Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Uchishtha Ganapathy is one of the 32 forms of Ganesha, mostly worshipped in an impure state and only after receiving the Deeksha from a realised guru. He is assumed to be having oral sex with Neela Saraswathi where his trunk is exploring the yoni of Neela Saraswathi which is nothing but kamakhya. Neela Saraswati holds uchishtha Ganapathy penis, stroking it up and down. 
He accepts anything without differentiating and often worshipped in vama marga. 
Devipuram practices UG, I am an initiate of devipuram guruji (amritananda natha). These are his pictures. 
[image]

The 37 beeja vidya is his ultimate mantra, where he is fornicating with Neela Saraswathi and both are very close to orgasm!!

[image]

Comment: Trunk is not mouth... its an organ for breathing. You must be knowing many controversies surrounding devipuram...