# What are the sources relating Uchchhishta Ganapati?

Tags: tantra, ganesha

I want to know the sources where I can learn more about worshipping and doing sadhana of Uchchhishta Ganapati?

Comment: Hope you get some answers on this eventually, that form of Ganpathy is so fascinating ! Off the wall, pics made me do a double take. One of the things I like most about Hinduism is the huge number of different representations with the gods/goddesses, to appeal to all kinds of different people, all kinds of different devotees. Fantastic. It’s so awesome :D

Comment: @devibhakt Indeed It is Awesome. I really hope we get good answers on this question.

Comment: Related answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33763/4732

Comment: @Rickross thank you for commenting, but is that really the only source?

Comment: No there can be more sources .. others may write answers here. Please wait.  @AspiringLearner

Comment: Looks like no one gave reply yet but sometimes I see ppl posting detailed helpful replies to questions posted two-three years ago, or even like four-five years ago. So, maybe at a later point someone knowledgeable will see this question & answer. In meantime I came across one more link from here w/ some photos of this form of Ganpathi : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37775/confusion-on-ucchista-ganesh-appearance