# Is Ucchista ganapati mentioned in puranas?

Tags: puranas, ganesha, ganapati

Is Ucchista ganapati mentioned in Puranas?
Is the story of Ucchista ganapati mentioned in scriptures?

Comment: Check this: [About Ucchista Ganapati and why is it regarded as the highest Ganesha form](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33760/about-ucchistaganapathi-and-why-its-regarded-as-highest-ganesha-form/33763#33763). It doesn’t talk of Puranas but talks of tantra

Comment: Do Ucchista ganapati is myth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32 forms of Lord Ganesha are mentioned in Mudgala Purana one among which is Ucchishtha Ganapati.

From [this article](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dwatrimshath_Ganesa_Dhyana_Slokas) (which names the 32 forms and their Dhyana Shlokas) on Hindupedia.com:

> 4.Pingala (Sidhi ) Ganapathi (The occult Ganesa)
>
> Pakva chootha kalpa manjarim ikshu danda thila modhakai saha ,
> Udwahan parasu hastha they Nama sri samrudhipatha deva Pingala.
>
> Salutations to the reddish brown coloured god armed with axe in his
> hand , who signifies plenty , Who holds ripe mango , bouquet of
> turmeric , sugarcane and sesame sweet.
>
> **5. Uchishta Ganapathi** (The Ganesa who has left remnants)
>
> Neelabjam dadimi veena saali gunjaksha suthrakam,
>  Dadadad uchishta
> naamaayam Ganesa pathu mokshadha
>
> Let The Ganapathi called the Ganapathi who gives the left over. Who
> holds a blue lotus, Pomegranate, Veena , rosary

The linked article is mentioning the Dhyana Slokas for all the 32 forms of Lord Ganesha mentioned in the Mudgala Purana.

> According to Mudgala Purana , a book dealing with Lord Ganesa, there
> are thirty two forms of Ganesa. These are listed described along with
> pictures and Dhyana Slokas are in a Kannada book called Sri Thathwa
> nidhi, in the chapter on Shiva Nidhi. These pictures along with the
> slokas are sculpturally represented along with Dhyana Slokas in the
> temple at Nanjangud as well as Chamaraja nagar near Mysore

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33763/4732) provides some more details about the Tantric method of worshipping this particular form of Ganapati.

Also, [Mudgala Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudgala_Purana), referred to in the Hindupedia article, is a minor Purana (Upapurana).

> The Mudgala Purana (Sanskrit:मुद्गल पुराणम्; mudgala purāṇam) is a
> Hindu religious text dedicated to the Hindu deity Ganesha (Gaṇeśa). It
> is an upapurāṇa that includes many stories and ritualistic elements
> relating to Ganesha. The Ganesha Purana and the Mudgala Purana are
> core scriptures for devotees of Ganesha, known as Ganapatyas
> (Gāṇapatya). These are the only two Purana that are exclusively
> dedicated to Ganesha.